# Running MadGraph on SLURM cluster

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, simulation, physics, montecarlo

Does anybody have experience with running mg5_aMC@NLO on a SLURM cluster? I would like to know how to write a batch script. I was told that the paradigm it uses is the "embarassingly parallel", and there are no examples in the SLURM wiki page. I would like to avoid wasting computational resources.

Thank you in advance.